# Understanding batch_dot() in Keras with Tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to understand this piece of code (from [here](https://github.com/johnsmithm/multi-heads-attention-image-classification/blob/master/multi-heads-attention-mnist.py)) which implements dot-product attention using matrix multiplication between two tensors. Specifically, the batch_dot() function from Keras backend is used between two tensors both with variable first dimension. batch_dot() seems to perform differently in this case as opposed to when the first dimension is specified.

MWE:

Fixed first dimension, works as expected

```
q = K.ones(shape=(36,8,24))
k = K.ones(shape=(36,8,24))
print(K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[1,1]))
```

returns

```
Tensor("MatMul_8:0", shape=(?, 36, 24, 24), dtype=float32)
```

and,

```
print(K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[2,2]))
```

returns

```
Tensor("MatMul_9:0", shape=(?, 36, 8, 8), dtype=float32)
```

However, defining q and k as follows:

```
q = Input(shape=(36,8,24))
k = Input(shape=(36,8,24))
print(q)
print(k)
```

(variable first dimension)

```
Tensor("input_24:0", shape=(?, 36, 8, 24), dtype=float32)
Tensor("input_25:0", shape=(?, 36, 8, 24), dtype=float32)
```

Output dimensions from batch_dot() operation is unexpected:

```
K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[1,1])
<tf.Tensor 'MatMul_11:0' shape=(?, 36, 24, 24) dtype=float32>
K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[2,2])
<tf.Tensor 'MatMul_12:0' shape=(?, 36, 24, 24) dtype=float32>
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/batch_dot),arguments to `axes` specify the dimensions which get removed during the operation, however I am unable to connect this definition to the outputs above. Does the first dimension (with value `?`) get counted for the arguments of `axes`?

Comment: What's your version of keras and tensorflow ? My return is `Tensor("MatMul:0", shape=(36, 24, 24), dtype=float32)` and `Tensor("MatMul_1:0", shape=(36, 8, 8), dtype=float32)` in your previous example.

Comment: My Keras version is 2.2.4, and Tensorflow version is 1.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the first dimension (with value ?) get counted for the arguments
>   of axes?

Yes, it is counted.

The fact is that the first dimension in [`Input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Input) layer, in the above example, is batch size while in [`K.ones()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/ones) it is not. As a result, axes [3, 3] for Input is equal to axes [2, 2] in `K.ones()`. In your code, the following two [`batch_dot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/batch_dot) are equal:

```
q = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(36, 8, 24)) # shape =(?, 36,8,24)
k = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(36, 8, 24)) # shape =(?, 36,8,24)
print(tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(q, k, axes=[3, 3]))

q = tf.keras.backend.ones(shape=(36, 8, 24))
k = tf.keras.backend.ones(shape=(36, 8, 24))
print(tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(q, k, axes=[2, 2]))
```

Note that, in `K.ones()`, if the shape was symbolic, we cannot return a variable, and will return a dynamically-shaped tensor instead. What does it mean? See following example for better understanding:

```
a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(30,))
c = tf.keras.backend.ones(shape=tf.shape(a))
print(c) # shape=(?, 30)
d = tf.keras.backend.ones(shape=(30, 40))
print(d) # shape=(30,40)
```

---

> Output dimensions from batch_dot() operation is unexpected

```
K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[1,1])
<tf.Tensor 'MatMul_11:0' shape=(?, 36, 24, 24) dtype=float32>
K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[2,2])
<tf.Tensor 'MatMul_12:0' shape=(?, 36, 24, 24) dtype=float32>
```

*Why on earth this happens while axes are different?*

To answer this question, we should know about the underlying implementation of `batch_dot`. If the rank of input tensors is not 2, then our `batch_dot` behaves as [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) operation that one of the input tensors is conjugate transposed. As a result, when our input tensors have a rank of 3 and we set the axis, to 0 or 1 they calculated the same things but when set axes to 2 it calculated something different:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [3, 2, 1]]])  # rank 3

b = np.array([[[1, 3, 3],
               [2, 2, 0]]])  # rank 3

a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(b, dtype=tf.float32)

c = tf.matmul(a, b, adjoint_a=True, adjoint_b=False)  # when axes is [0,0] or [1,1]
d = tf.matmul(a, b, adjoint_a=False, adjoint_b=True)  # when axes is [2,2]
print(c.shape)  # shape=(1,3,3)
print(d.shape)  # shape=(1,2,2)
```

The same things happened in your example:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [3, 2, 1]]])

b = np.array([[[1, 3, 3],
               [2, 2, 0]]])

q = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 2, 3))  
k = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 2, 3))  
res1 = tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(q, k, axes=0)
res2 = tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(q, k, axes=1)
res3 = tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(q, k, axes=2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    feed_dic = {q: a, k: b}
    print(sess.run(res1, feed_dict=feed_dic))
    print(20 * '-')
    print(sess.run(res2, feed_dict=feed_dic))
    print(20 * '-')
    print(sess.run(res3, feed_dict=feed_dic))
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it does not explain the output dimensions from the last two commands in the question. The comment by @giser_yugang makes me think if this behavior is a version issue...

Answer (score 3):

Things will be clear if you look at the source code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L1437

we can directly go [line1507](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L1514)

```
if ndim(x) == 2 and ndim(y) == 2:
    if axes[0] == axes[1]:
      out = math_ops.reduce_sum(math_ops.multiply(x, y), axes[0])
    else:
      out = math_ops.reduce_sum(
          math_ops.multiply(array_ops.transpose(x, [1, 0]), y), axes[1])
else: 
    adj_x = None if axes[0] == ndim(x) - 1 else True
    adj_y = True if axes[1] == ndim(y) - 1 else None
    out = math_ops.matmul(x, y, adjoint_a=adj_x, adjoint_b=adj_y)
```

As it shows, it only checks the `adj_x` and `adj_y` and doesn't pass the `axes` parameter to `math_ops.matmul` method. That is the reason you are getting the same result when `axes` is `[1,1]` and `[2,2]`.

We can use below code to verify:

```
q = K.ones(shape=range(1, 10))
k = K.ones(shape=range(1, 10))
for i in range(10): print(i, K.batch_dot(q,k,axes=[i,i]))
```

it will print

```
0 Tensor("MatMul_7:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
1 Tensor("MatMul_8:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
2 Tensor("MatMul_9:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
3 Tensor("MatMul_10:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
4 Tensor("MatMul_11:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
5 Tensor("MatMul_12:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
6 Tensor("MatMul_13:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
7 Tensor("MatMul_14:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
8 Tensor("MatMul_15:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8), dtype=float32)
9 Tensor("MatMul_16:0", shape=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9), dtype=float32)
```

Except when `i` is 8, all others are returning the same result.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.